# how to get filename entered by user in "save as" dialog after javascript anchor.click()

Tags: javascript, html

I use HTML5 anchor.download attribute for saving a file locally.

The save dialog allows the user to change the file name but I can't find any record of this in anchor.

```
var anchor = document.createElement("A");
anchor.href= (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
anchor.download = filename;
anchor.click();
```

How do I recover the changed file name after click()?

Comment: Well, no, if the user changes the filename when downloading a file, it's probably not something you'll be able to get

Comment: Its up to the user, not the programmer to determine the name the file is saved under.

Comment: @Bindrid yes but the programmer ought to be free to display the name as chosen by the user

Comment: I am not sure if it matters but not all browsers support anchor.download.

Comment: You can't. Not disclosing details of the user's file name choice and file system details is part of privacy policy.

Comment: that's the answer then?